# System shutdown after page fault in non-paged area

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bsod

I shut down my system after a blue screen error of a page fault in non-paged area. Now I can't turn it back on. The lights are blinking, HDD is working, CD ROM is working, and all of the fans are running, but no beep and no video on screen. If I remove the RAM it just beeps.

Does this happen because of bad RAM or a CPU? How do I find it?

Comment: On which OS....?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: How many sticks of ram do you have?  Remove one at a time until it boots.

In my mind, the mobo beeping with both sticks out means the mobo is fine, and at least getting to that point in the post.

Try some known good memory.  Also, what lights are blinking?  Is it a Dell with numbered diagnostic lights on the front?

Comment: Yep, if you have more than one stick of RAM, try one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all parts not needed for the system to POST. If it POSTs, add them back one at a time until you find the problem. If not, swap parts with known-good parts one at a time until you find the problem.